# JUnit tests run in eclipse return errors even though I have expected annotation

Tags: java, eclipse, unit-testing, junit, junit4

(This is a follow up question to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1836364/bad-form-for-junit-test-to-throw-exception) one.)

I'm having a problem with JUnit4 tests in eclipse. I'm trying to use the @Test(expected=...) annotation to unit test exception throwing. The problem is that when I run the tests, they come back as errors instead of passing, even though I'm expecting the exceptions to be thrown.

I'm using eclipse 3.4.0 and JUnit 4.3.1.

Here's the code:

Class to test:

```
public class IPAddress
{
    private byte[] octets;

    private IPAddress()
    {
        octets = new byte[4];
    }

    public IPAddress(String addr) throws InvalidIPAddressException
    {
        this();

        if(addr == null || !isValid(addr))
            throw new InvalidIPAddressException(addr);

        String strOctets[] = addr.split("\\.");

        for (int i = 0; i < strOctets.length; i++)
            octets[i] = Byte.parseByte(strOctets[i]);
    }

    public static boolean isValid(String addr)
    {
        String strOctets[] = addr.split("\\.");

        if (strOctets.length != 4)
            return false;

        for (int i = 0; i < strOctets.length; i++)
        {
            try
            {
                int num = Integer.parseInt(strOctets[i]);

                if (num < 0 || num > 255)
                    return false;
            } catch (NumberFormatException e)
            {
                return false;
            }
        }

        return true;
    }

    public byte[] getOctets()
    {
        return octets;
    }
}
```

Exception:

```
public class InvalidIPAddressException extends Exception
{
    public InvalidIPAddressException(String addr)
    {
        super("\"" + addr + "\" is not a valid IP address");
    }
}
```

Test case:

```
public class IPAddressTest extends TestCase
{
    @Test(expected=InvalidIPAddressException.class)
    public void testNullParameter() throws InvalidIPAddressException
    {
        @SuppressWarnings("unused")
        IPAddress addr = new IPAddress(null);
        fail("InvalidIPAddressException not thrown.");
    }

    @Test(expected=InvalidIPAddressException.class)
    public void testHostnameParameter() throws InvalidIPAddressException
    {
        @SuppressWarnings("unused")
        IPAddress addr = new IPAddress("http://www.google.com");
        fail("InvalidIPAddressException not thrown.");
    }

    @Test
    public void testValidIPAddress() throws InvalidIPAddressException
    {
        IPAddress addr = new IPAddress("127.0.0.1");
        byte[] octets = addr.getOctets();

        assertTrue(octets[0] == 127);
        assertTrue(octets[1] == 0);
        assertTrue(octets[2] == 0);
        assertTrue(octets[3] == 1);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        TestRunner.run(IPAddressTest.class);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks like you're mixing up JUnit 3 and 4 code.  `TestRunner` is part of JUnit 3, so doesn't look at the annotations at all.

Try removing `extends TestCase` and changing `TestRunner.run(IPAddressTest.class);` to `JUnitCore.runClasses(IPAddressTest.class);` (you'll need to add the imports as required).

Comment: Also, if you're using eclipse, you can use the built in testrunner - right click on the test class in package explorer and choose Run As -> JUnit test.  The JUnitCore.runClasses method doesn't actually give any output so this may be a better way.

Answer (score 0):

Likely because when you try to instantiate the InvalidIPAddressException the constructor throw a NullPointerException when it tries to concatenate the string in it.

```
public InvalidIPAddressException(String addr)
{
    super("\"" + addr + "\" is not a valid IP address"); // NPE while concatenate
}
```