# If an exception is thrown will test fail?

Tags: java, junit

If a junit test throws an exception :

```
public void mytest throws InvalidUsageException
```

Does this mean that if a test throws an InvalidUsageException the test will then fail ?

If so is it better design to wrap the exception in a try/catch block and explicitly fail of the exception is thrown ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1836364/bad-form-for-junit-test-to-throw-exception

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The test will fail if this exception is thrown.
If your test is to see whether there is a certain exception thrown, you should start your test like

```
@Test(expected=InvalidUsageException.class)
  public void mytest {
    ...
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

First off, yes your test will fail.

Secondly, I wouldn't wrap with a try catch.  If an exception is occurring, you want to let it happen so you are aware that there is an error occurring, and not just a bug in the method itself.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, thes will fail. If you expect exceptin then use `@Test(expect=ExceptionClassName.class`

Answer (score 1):

What you say could be one solution

```
public void mytest() {
  try {
     // your code
     fail();
  } catch (InvalidUsageException e) {
     // success 
  }
}
```

A faster approach (but I wouldn't say clearer)

```
@Test (expected = Exception.class)
public void mytest() {
  // your code
}
```

More such examples here http://www.vogella.com/articles/JUnit/article.html